# de\serialize xml contains lists of object to lists of objects

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

I'm trying to save lists of object to a xml file. But when I'm save once it delete the before saving. I mean if I save on xml file 1 list of "Radar" and than save on the save xml file list of "Observer" it saves only the last list I save. There is any way to save them both ? 
My code to save :

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Observer>));

                using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\MapSample\bin\Debug\ListObserver.xml"))
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, list);
                }
```

Hope you understand. Thanks in advice.

Edit : 
I creat new object that contain the lists as a properties. And now All the list in one xml file. 
The object :

```
 [Serializable()]
    public class SaveObject
    {
        public List<Radar> listRadars = new List<Radar>();
        public List<Ikun> listIkuns = new List<Ikun>();
        public List<Observer> listObservers = new List<Observer>();
        public XmlSerializer ser;

        public SaveObject(List<Observer> listObservers, List<Ikun> listIkuns,List<Radar> listRadars)
        {
            this.listIkuns = listIkuns;
            this.listRadars = listRadars;
            this.listObservers = listObservers;
        }

        public SaveObject()
        {
            ser = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
        }
    }
```

The serialize function :

```
public void Serialize(SaveObject SO)
        {
            if (IfPathToSave) // Select save - not auto ! 
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SaveObject));

                using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FilePath))
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, SO);
                }
            }
            else // auto save ! 
            {

                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SaveObject));

                using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\MapSample\bin\Debug\AutoSave.xml"))
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, SO);
                }
            }
        }
```

Hope it will help any one sometime. Enjoy. :)

Comment: You have to create a new serializable object "ObserverCollection" contains a property of your list.

Comment: Do you mean to create an object "SaveObject" that contains few lists as properties ?

Comment: You are trying to serialize single `List<Observer>` in given code, but mentioning another list. Are you trying to save 2 different lists into the same xml? Use different file name for them or create more complex serialization type, which will hold both lists (not sure if `List<List<Observer>>` will do, more likely yes).

Comment: I though about the option to save any list to different file xml but I want them in the same file.. I will try now to create object save that contain lists as properties.  Sinatr what do you mean ? Can you give me an example to save some lists in the same xml file.

Comment: Well, I'm success. Thanks for CodeInNet on the idea. I editing the question with the soulotion

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 lists and doing it this way (wrong)

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Observer>));
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\MapSample\bin\Debug\ListObserver.xml"))
    serializer.Serialize(writer, listA);
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\MapSample\bin\Debug\ListObserver.xml"))
    serializer.Serialize(writer, listB);
```

then `listB` will overwrite `ListObserver.xml` content.

You can try this

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<List<Observer>>));
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\MapSample\bin\Debug\ListObserver.xml"))
    serializer.Serialize(writer, new List<List<Observer>>(new[] {listA, listB}));
```

If it doesn't works (for whatever reasons), then simply create serialization object

```
public class SerializationObject
{
    public List<Observer> ListA {get; set;}
    public List<Observer> ListB {get; set;}
}
```

and use it

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerializationObject));
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\MapSample\bin\Debug\ListObserver.xml"))
    serializer.Serialize(writer, new SerializationObject() { ListA = listA, ListB = listB });
```